# How to burn an ISO to my USB

Tags: usb, iso

So, I was tryna burn an ISO to my USB. The ISO file I am using is that of Arch Linux, I was not able to find any good softwares in paticular, if anyone here has a good experience with any software, please let me know!

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long should it take to create a bootable USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435033/how-long-should-it-take-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use GNOME Disks to write ISO's to any hard disk/ssd/usb drive. AFAIK, this is the best method in Ubuntu 16.04-20.04. You can even make ISO's with that tool :)